# Logic to Implement Parent Child Relationship in efficient manner

Tags: objective-c, logic, parent-child

I have a Table where Parent Child Relation ship is stored as:
ChildID     Name    ParentID
  1          A1       Null
  2          A2        1
  3          B1       Null
  4          A3        2
  5          A4        1
I m Woking on Objective C and I need to Generate a text File in Manner:
 Name =A1>
 Name =A2>
 Name =A3/> 
 Name =A2/>
 Name =A4/>
 Name =B1/>

I was using a approch where I catch the Last Element (Id=5) first and then checking all other nodes to get its Parent Nodes. n Complexity comes to be as n*n-1, Is there any other better approach as this approach is not a succes when we  have lasrge data in Database.

Database Structure is flexible, we can change that, if there is something better...

Looking for your help and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your output structure, I assume your data represents a tree. You therefore have a simple "get all children of a node" request as `SELECT childId, name FROM tree WHERE parentId = ?`, which lets you perform a standard tree traversal. Pseudocode:

```
def displayNode(node)  
  children = selectChildren(node.id)
  if (empty(children)) 
    print '<'+node.name+'/>'
  else 
    print '<'+node.name+'>'
    for (child in children) 
      displayNode(child)
    print '</'+node.name+'>'
```

An optimization, if running one query per node is too much (which probably is the case) is to run a single query to fetch all the data and place it in an optimized data structure:

```
for (node in selectAllNodes())
  nodes[node.parent].append(node);

def selectChildren(id)
  return nodes[id]
```